# Capistrano: Storing database password for Laravel

Tags: laravel, capistrano, capistrano3

I am using capistrano as a deployment tool for Laravel based app. The .env file that stores all server credentials are created in the process of deployment. Here is an overview of build logic (deploy.rb).

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.8.1"

set :application, "my_app"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:me/myapp.git"
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/myapp'

# Environment variables
set :app_path, '/var/www/myapp/current'
set :app_debug, true
set :app_env, 'local'
set :app_key, 'base64:k1IYcD0k8Q59nDOBds0sgPVJye/vy85ovAS8GQecRuI='
set :app_log_level, 'debug'
set :app_url, 'http://localhost'

set :db_connection, 'mysql'
set :db_host, '127.0.0.1'
set :db_port, '3306'
set :db_name, 'my_db_name'
set :db_user, 'my_db_user'
set :db_password, 'mypassword'

set :keep_releases, 3

# Do composer install
namespace :composer do
    desc "Running Composer install ..."
    task :install do
        on roles(:app) do
            within release_path do
                execute :composer, "install --no-dev"
                execute :composer, "dumpautoload"
            end
        end
    end
end

# Do database migrations
namespace :database do
    desc "Running database migrations ..."
    task :migrate do
        on roles(:app) do
            execute "php #{fetch(:app_path)}/artisan migrate"
        end
    end
end

# Create .env file
namespace :environment do
    desc "Setting up environment variables ..."
    task :set_variables do
        on roles(:app) do
              puts ("Creating environment configuration file...")
              execute "cat /dev/null > #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"

              execute "echo APP_NAME=#{fetch(:application)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo APP_ENV=#{fetch(:app_env)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo APP_KEY=#{fetch(:app_key)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo APP_DEBUG=#{fetch(:app_debug)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo APP_LOG_LEVEL=#{fetch(:app_log_level)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo APP_URL=#{fetch(:app_url)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"

              execute "echo DB_CONNECTION=#{fetch(:db_connection)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo DB_HOST=#{fetch(:db_host)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo DB_PORT=#{fetch(:db_port)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo DB_DATABASE=#{fetch(:db_name)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo DB_USERNAME=#{fetch(:db_user)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
              execute "echo DB_PASSWORD=#{fetch(:db_password)} >> #{fetch(:app_path)}/.env"
        end
    end

    task :set_permissions do
        on roles(:app) do
            puts ("Set directory permissions to writtable...")
            execute "chmod -R 777 #{fetch(:app_path)}/storage"
            execute "chmod -R 777 #{fetch(:app_path)}/bootstrap/cache"
        end
    end
end

namespace :deploy do
  after :updated, "composer:install"
  after :finished, "environment:set_variables"
  after :finished, "environment:set_permissions"
  after :finished, "database:migrate"
end
```

As you can see the database password are stored in the file itself, which is not a secure way. How to keep the password separate? I am new to capistrano and ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple mechanisms at your disposal.

The first one I would consider is using linked_files. Something like

```
append :linked_files, '.env'
```

in your `config/deploy.rb` will cause that file inside the deploy directory to be linked to `shared/config/deploy.rb` outside the deploy directory. You would set up that file manually, and then have Capistrano link to it on deploy.

Secondly, you can add environment variables to your system, allowing you to just read them and skip the `.env` file entirely.

Finally, you could create a new YAML file in your repository, and maybe gitignore it, and then read it for the passwords. This will work, because the logic to read the Capistrano configuration runs locally on the deploying computer.